# How to overwrite Widget class to set `name` attribute in ipywidgets?

Tags: ipywidgets

For debugging purposes I would like to be able to set `name` attribute for each widget I create, for example:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets

button1 = widgets.Button(description = "Click me", name = "button1")
```

Unfortunately ipywidgets Widget class doesn't have `name` attribute. One workaround I came up with is doing this:

```
button1 = widgets.Button(description = "Click me")
button1.__setattr__("name", "button1")
```

which works but seems really bad to me. I would like to somehow overwrite Widget class from ipywidgets so that every widget can have `name` attribute specified in constructor. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

**With a subclass**

```
class NamedButton(widgets.Button):
def __init__(self, name, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
    self.name = name

button1 = NamedButton(name = "button1", description = "Click me")
display(button1)
display(button1.name)
```

Output:

```
'button1'
```

**With a dynamic attribute**

```
button1 = widgets.Button(description = "Click me")
button1.name = "button1"
display(button1.name)
```

Output

```
'button1'
```